# How to return custom JSON response in DRF?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have created API for News model:

**models.py**

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**serializers.py**

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = [
            "id",
            "title",
            "created_at",
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
class NewsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
    queryset = News.objects.all()
```

The current result of this API which is below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "testing1",
        "created_at": "2022-04-02T16:05:08.353708Z",
    }
]
```

And my question is there any ways to change the response format like below? I can not figure out how to make with Django DRF.

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "message": "Success",
  "data": {
    "updatedAt": "2020-08-31 17:49:15",
    "serverTime": "2022-03-23 15:10:11",
    "news": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "testing1",
        "created_at": "2022-04-02T16:05:08.353708Z",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should the data "status", "message","updatedAt" come from?

Comment: Status and message is custom like: 0 - Success 1 - Internal error 2- User not registered 4 - Bad request

updatedAt will reflect time if there is change on data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `list` method in `ModelViewSet` to return custom `response`.

```
class NewsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
    queryset = News.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # call the original 'list' to get the original response.
        response_data = super(NewsViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)

        data = {
              "status": 0,
              "message": "Success",
              "data": {
                      "updatedAt": "2020-08-31 17:49:15",
                      "serverTime": "2022-03-23 15:10:11",
              "news": [{
                        "id": obj['id'],
                        "title": obj['title'],
                        "created_at": obj['created_at'],
                          } for obj in response_data.data]
                      }
            }

        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider another way:

```
class ResponseOptsMixin:

    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        
        result_data = {
            "status": 0,
            "message": "Success",
            "data": {
                "updatedAt": "2020-08-31 17:49:15",
                "serverTime": "2022-03-23 15:10:11",
            },
        }
        model_name = self.queryset.model._meta.model_name
        result_data["data"][model_name] = response.data
        response.data = result_data

        return response


class NewsViewSet(ResponseOptsMixin, ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

Use this mixin wherever you needed